# Trying to get username from User model using user_id Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting an error **undefined variable** when I'm trying to get username (`$user->name`) from `User model` using `id` which is foreign key (`$feedback->user_id`) of Feedback model.

```html
@php
   
use App\Feedback;
use App\User;

$feedbacks = Feedback::all();
@endphp
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<a href="/admin">ADMIN DASHBOARD</a> |<a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"> LOGOUT</a><br><br>
<h3>Feedbacks</h3>
<table border="1">
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Left By</th><th>Feedback</th></tr>
@foreach ($feedbacks as $feedback)
                
                <tr>
                <td>{{ $feedback->id}}</td>
                <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $feedback->feedback }}</td>
                </tr>
$uid=$feedback->user_id;
$user= User::find($uid);

@endforeach
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You declare `$user` variable *after* you try to use it

Comment: True @HtmHell another point is Prabhat doesn't make correct use of the VMC and ORM model. There shouldn't be any declarations in a View. The best way to solve this is by making use of mutators https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators

Comment: @HtmlHell still getting the same error even if I declare $user variable before I use it

Comment: What does `dd($user);` give you @Prabhat Did you declare it in the controller? If the user has to be logged in, you could make use of `Auth::user()->name;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a **relation** between `feedback` and `user` (If you don't have one already). Your relation would be put within the `Feedback` model and look like this:

```
// Feedback.php

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

This will relate the `feedback` to the `user` using the `user_id` on the `feedback` table.

After this, when calling `feedback` within your controller, you can then **eager load** the `user` relation with each `feedback`. This can be done within the following:

```
$feedbacks = Feedback::with('user')->get();
```

Finally, within your template, you will able to call the `user` through each `feedback` by doing the following:

```
{{ $feedback->user->name }}
```

**Note**: This example assumes `name` is a field on your `user` table.

Comment: thank you ... if we have owner_id for foregn key 
    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'owner_id');
    }